# css and images in uploaddir, different response in different browsers

Tags: images, css, uploads

I have some pages to demonstrate how to include and use some code. Therefore I load js, css and images with sftp to a directory in /wp-content/uploads/ and describe how to use it.

Now I would like to demonstrate Leaflet Draw. There is a css file loading an image. If I call the page, it works, but the image does not load in Firefox and Chrome. I get a 403 error. If I call the image only, I see it. It has the right Content-Type. Safari works as expected. If I move these files to /wp-content/mydir/ it works with all browsers.

If I change spritesheet.svg to spritesheet.png it is the same behavior.

I know, there are some special settings for uploaddir. Which ones I have to change to make it work? Thank you very much.

Comment: this is unlikely to be a WordPress coding issue and more likely to be an Nginx/Apache issue, especially since directly visiting the URL works. Check your hosts security protections. Otherwise keep in mind what you're doing with the uploads folder is not normal or standard. Those assets are supposed to be in the plugins folder, or referenced via attachment IDs to generate URLs at runtime, then embedded with blocks/shortcodes/widgets. I would be suspicious of `leaflet.draw`, it could be interpreted as a file extension and a malformed URL

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it was a .htaccess issue. I am only confused that it worked with Safari.